# Unrecognised database format when build connection to excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build an add-in which will build a connection to an optional database (excel or access file).

It's fine with access but when try with an Excel file the below error happens:

> "Unrecognized database format"

```
Sub export_data()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim flg As FileDialog
    Dim dtpth As String


    Set flg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With flg
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add Description:="Database file type", Extensions:="*.xls,*.xlsx,*.xlsm,*.accdb"
        .Filters.Add Description:="All types", Extensions:="*.*"
        .Title = "Chon file database"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            dtpth = .SelectedItems(1)
            Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = dtpth
        End If
    End With

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        If Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = "*ls*" Then
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & dtpth & "Extended properties='Excel 16.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
            .Open
        Else
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & dtpth & ";"
            .Open
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Cause i'm new in this section, i can't debug the code by myself
Could you please point out what make the code be wrong? I try research somewhere but most of them in access not excel

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon in your connectionstring, and probably the quotes if your filename contains spaces.

The line

```
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & dtpth & "Extended properties='Excel 16.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
```

should look like

```
.ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & dtpth & "';Extended properties='Excel 16.0 xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
```

[Here's](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) a good reference for the possible connectionstring formats.